# Show that if $A^{n}=I$ then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times m$ matrix which satisfies $A^{n}=1$ for some $n$, then why is $A$ necessarily diagonalizable.

Not sure if this is helpful, but here's my thinking so far: We know that $A$ satisfies $p(x)=x^{n}-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1)$.  If $A=I$ it is clearly diagonalizable so we may assume that $A$ is a root of the other factor.

Edit: Actually, I'm a bit confused and not even sure if we can say that much.  Since the ring of $m \times m$ matrices is not an integral domain, we can not conclude that if $A-I \not = 0$ then $(A^{n-1}+\ldots+A+I)=0$, correct?

Comment: @Ram A is invertible, but is $A-I$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes yes I got it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $P(X):=X^n-1$. Assume we work on an algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$ of characteristic $0$. We have, since  $P$ kills $A$, that the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits on $\mathbb K[X]$ and has distinct roots. We conclude by [Theorem 4.11](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/minpolyandappns.pdf).

Comment: But is this still true if the field is not algebraically closed? like here if $A \in M_m(\mathbb R)$

Comment: I think your proof only works in characteristic 0 ;)

Comment: @N.S. Yes, I've added that.

Comment: My algebra is very very rusty, so I am not sure about this: I think in positive characteristic $X^n-1$ splits if and only if $p$ doesn't divide $n$. So in that situation the proof would still work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Question: how does this solution change if the vs is not finite dimensional?

Comment: Why does $P$ kills $A$ imply that the minimal polynomial has distinct roots? Doesn't $P$ always kill $A$ by Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Comment: @Leo Since we may have that $m\neq n$, $P$ is not necessarily the characteristic polynomial. We know that the minimal polynomial divides $P$ if $P$ kills the matrix $A$.

Comment: the notes attached to the answer are wonderful

Answer (score 6):

Davide showed what happens in an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

If the field is not algebraically closed, the result is not true, for example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Satisfies $A^4=I$ but is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$, as it has complex eigenvalues.

Also 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

is not diagonalizable in an algebraically closed field of characteristic $2$, but $A^2=I_2$. Note that the reason why $A$ is not diagonalizable is simple: both eigenvalues are $1$, thus if $A$ is diagonalizable, $D=I$ and thus $A=PDP^{-1}=I$ contradiction.